# I'm having an error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, typeerror

I'm really confused. I made classes similar to this the one with this one with no errors. So I don't see the problem with this one. Please help!

```
class champ_info:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def name(self):
        print({self.name}) #I also tried using it with out the {}

v = champ_info('henry')
v.name()
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

You have an attribute with the same name as a method. When you assign `self.name` its object shadows the function object you really wanted.

```
class champ_info:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name    # <-- this shadows the same-named method
```

`v.name()` translates to (1) get object referenced by "name" (its the string `'henry'`) and (2) call that object. You can't call a string, so boom.

To solve, just come up with a better name for the method, hopefully something that gives a good hint of what it does.

```
class champ_info:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_me(self):
        print(f"{self.name}")

v = champ_info('henry')
v.print_me()
```